# Spring Cloud Config not decrypting the config server password

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I've been working on Spring Cloud Config for a while. I have a requirement of securing the config data. As per Spring Cloud Documentation I have configured the *server.jks* and added to classpath. Now I am able to encrypt and decrypt remote config data.

For making the config server secure I have added Spring Security Starter and assigned credentials (password decrypted). For some reason the application is throwing exceptions that it does not have key store on the classpath. After googling it for a while I found that the keystore should go to *bootstrap.yml* instead of *application.yml*. This is also not working, what am I missing here?

You can find the yml config files on GitHub:
[SpringConfigData](https://github.com/PreetamMyneni/SpringConfigData)

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot decrypt: key=security.user.password
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.decrypt(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:195) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.decrypt(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:164) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.initialize(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:94) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener$DelegatingEnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.initialize(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:333) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:640) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:343) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.test.TestConfigServerApplication.main(TestConfigServerApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No decryption for FailsafeTextEncryptor. Did you configure the keystore correctly?
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration$FailsafeTextEncryptor.decrypt(EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.java:151) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.decrypt(EnvironmentDecryptApplicationInitializer.java:187) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Do you have the JCE installed as described in the docs? http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/1.0.3/spring-cloud.html#_cloud_native_applications

Comment: yes i have setup. The encrytion/decrytion is working for remote properties which are in my svn.

Comment: I have one more observation after going through the documentation again. I have given a try with environment variables. (-Dencrypt.keyStore.location=classpath:/server.jks -Dencrypt.keyStore.password=springcloudconfigserver -Dencrypt.keyStore.alias=springcloudconfigserver -Dencrypt.keyStore.secret=springcloudconfigserver) this time its working. For all those who are scratching head with asymetric config this is a work around.

Answer (score 9):

I have had this problem. To set symmetric encryption in the latest versions of spring cloud, you just have to set the `encrypt.key` property in the **bootstap.yml(or .properties)** with the required key (*it is recommended to set the key as an OS environmental variable and reference the variable in your file. This is for more security*)

However, as you discovered the properties in the bootsrap file are no more imported. You must add the following dependency into your pom file for the properties in that file to be loaded:

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After having done this every thing will work smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I was facing the same problem from the config client side. To resolve this, I added this dependency in the `pom.xml` and in `bootstarp.properties`/`bootstrap.yml` file, I added `encrypt.key` property as I was using symmetric encryption.

hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome. Found this after 4 hours of research of trying to run from intellij. Only adding bootstrap.properties was enough for me, dependency was not required for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is: move all properties from `bootstrap.yaml` to `application.yaml`.

Comment: This is not written in an encouraging way for someone to try. However as a last resort, I actually try it and it worked. Why does this work? Do you know if there can be any repercussions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `bootstrap.yml` passed using environment variables.

- `-Dencrypt.keyStore.location=classpath:/server.jks`
- `-Dencrypt.keyStore.password=springcloudconfigserver`
- `-Dencrypt.keyStore.alias=springcloudconfigserver`
- `-Dencrypt.keyStore.secret=springcloudconfigserver`

**Config Server** is not able to locate the properties in `bootstrap.yml` for asymmetric security. Symmetric works just fine

Comment: `bootstrap.xml` isn't a valid file, `bootstrap.yml` or `bootstrap.properties` are valid.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo that was yml file

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this error because my application was taking local `bootstrap.yml` instead of cloud config in the server. That's why it cannot decrypt and it fails.

Make sure local `bootstrap.yml` has this prop, which indicates to use `config.uri` to read the config from the server instead:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had into this problem when I ran projects in **IntelliJ IDEA** and had the following project structure:

```
.
├── config
│   └── application.yaml
├── api-users
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
└── config-server
    ├── pom.xml
    └── src
```

The project also used the file `config/application.yaml` when it was launched, which is why this error occurred.

After renaming the `config` directory to `configuration`, this problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I switched from `bootsrap.yaml` to `application.yaml` but forgot to remove `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` dependency from `pom.xml`.

To test I've added encrypted property to environment variables.