# Spring Cloud Config encrypt endpoint giving java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException with JDK11

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config, jce

I want to encrypt my passwords with Spring Cloud Config Server. Below are my file changes.

bootstrap.properties

```
encrypt.key=%gdba$!
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

With JDK1.8, After manually setting up JCE inside my JDK. I am able to get encrypted results after hitting

`POST : http://localhost:9090/config/encrypt`

But when I try same thing with JDK11, it is giving me below error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No encryption for FailsafeTextEncryptor. Did you configure the keystore correctly?
```

As per `https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html` JCE setup is not required after JDK8. Where am I going wrong.

Full stack trace :
[image]

Comment: Which distribution of the JDK 11 do you use?

Comment: @grekier I am using Java SE jdk11 by Oracle.

Comment: That was not expected... Do you have any more information with the error? Stack trace maybe?

Comment: Have you seen the different proposals at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938714/spring-cloud-config-not-decrypting-the-config-server-password ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked, but none of them helped.

Comment: @grekier Attached snapshot of full stack trace.

Comment: Can you run `jrunscript -e 'exit (println(javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES") >= 256));'` in a terminal (where JDK 11 is the default)
It should return `true`

Comment: @grekier Its giving me below error -

Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
script error: ReferenceError: "AES" is not defined in <string> at line number 1

Comment: The warning about Nashorn is OK but it seems that you do not have JCE correctly configured. Can you check "crypto.policy" in /conf/security/java.security in your JRE? Should be set to "unlimited" but might have been overridden somehow.

Comment: @grekier crypto.policy is set to unlimited in my /conf/security/java.security

Comment: Sorry @Rex, I'm out of ideas here. I'm pretty sure that there is something wrong/missing in your JRE. Eventually try with a different vendor? If you have a running example somewhere, I can try to run it on my side (I have zulu and amazon here) to confirm (or not).

Answer (score 0):

Adding this dependency solved the problem for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```