# Encryption using spring cloud config, java 11

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have added the property encrypt.key in bootstrap.properties file.
I am using java 11 and I am getting `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No encryption for FailsafeTextEncryptor Did you configure the keystore correctly?`, when I am trying to encrypt something using the spring cloud config encrypt endpoint.

Comment: Did you checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938714/spring-cloud-config-not-decrypting-the-config-server-password

Comment: Thank You @st.huber, problem solved.